# org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for a property

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

i am new to jsf and hibernate
i am just trying to add name in database through jsf and hibernate
i don't know what's wrong with my code
following is my code

newjsf.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
<title>JSF Hibernate CRUD Example</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>
<h:outputText value="Name"/><br/>
<h:inputText value="#{customer.name}"/>
<h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{customer.save()}"/>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Customer.java

```
package com.javaknowledge.entity;
import com.javaknowledge.dao.CustomerDao;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Customer implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer custID;
private String name;
private String msg;

public Customer() {
}

public Integer getcustID() {
    return custID;
}

public void setcustID(Integer custid) {
    this.name = custid;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}

public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}

    public void save(){
    CustomerDao dao = new CustomerDao();
    dao.addCustomer(this);
    this.msg = "ok insertation done";
}         


}
```

CustomerDao.java

```
package com.javaknowledge.dao;
import com.javaknowledge.entity.Customer;
import com.javaknowledge.util.HibernateUtil;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

public class CustomerDao {


public void addCustomer(Customer cust) {
    Transaction trns = null;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {
        trns = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(cust);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        if (trns != null) {
            trns.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.flush();
        session.close();
    }
}
}
```

Hibernate mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="com.javaknowledge.entity.Customer" table="C_name">
<id name="custId" type="java.lang.Integer" column="cust_id">
<generator class="identity"/>
</id>
<property name="name" type="string" column="name"/>
</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>


<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>  
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/college</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>

<property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>

<mapping resource="com/javaknowledge/entity/hibernate.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

hibernateutil.java

```
package com.javaknowledge.util;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;

public class HibernateUtil {
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void closeSessionFactory() {
    sessionFactory.close();
}
}
```

here is my error log..

```
An Error Occurred:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Stack Trace

    javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:[][1]591)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.javaknowledge.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:24)
        at com.javaknowledge.dao.CustomerDao.addCustomer(CustomerDao.java:18)
        at com.javaknowledge.entity.Customer.save(Customer.java:51)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
        at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
        at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
        ... 36 more

    Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for custId in class com.javaknowledge.entity.Customer
        at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:310)
        at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:304)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.getGetter(PropertyFactory.java:497)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierAttribute(PropertyFactory.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:163)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:520)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:148)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163)
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:400)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
        at com.javaknowledge.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:21)
        ... 49 more
```

tell me whats wrong ?

Comment: Question tags are important. Using unnecessary tags with unnecessary  code snippets diverts the question to the users who are not interested in the question at all. The root cause of the exception `org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for a property` is not related to JSF at all. Thus, this is not the subject of JSF rather it is a question of Hibernate / JPA.

Comment: And try using a more modern JPA2 based jsf tutorial. Lots of approaches are almost prehistoric.

Comment: i know you are taking about @ManagedBean and hibernate mapping.but later i changed my code to latest CIDR and i also move on to annotation for mapping. is there any thing else should i go for ? i think one more thing is i should go for latest hibernate isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for custId in class com.javaknowledge.entity.Customer

It looks as if you have a few typos. In your `Customer` class, rename `custID` to `custId` because your mapping expects a field named `custId`. Then rename the following methods...

```
public Integer getcustID() {
    return custID;
}

public void setcustID(Integer custid) {
    this.name = custid;
}
```

...to follow the camel-case convention and to use the renamed `custId`:

```
public Integer getCustId() {
    return custId;
}

public void setCustId(Integer custId) {
    this.custId = custId;
}
```

Also, in `setcustID` you're setting `name` instead of setting `custId`.

Comment: oh thanks, but still no output. i did those changes and now my jsf page is loading and than nothing happening next to it,no output no error !